# DELETE CASCADE ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new to sql, so i am exploring sql capabilities. Currently, i am trying to understand isolation levels and transactions. Suppose we have Table A and table B references Table A and also it has rule "on delete cascade".
So when i delete one row from Table A all the rows that references the specific row also deleted in table B.

1. Do we know what are exactly the commands that are executed behind the scenes? Because if i delete one row  also rows on table B are deleted?
2. Does these  Commands execute in one transaction?

2.a if i can set the transaction isolation level for delete on Table A,the isolation level will be the same for the commands that execute behind the scenes, correct?

3. Can this simple delete on table A fail, because for example while Transaction X deletes rows on table B because of a delete of row on table A, Transaction Y adds rows on table B. If i set the right isolation level will i avoid failing situations For Transaction X?

I would appreciate if you point me some links for further study about locking,concurrency,transaction,isolation levels in order to understand better these kinds of problems.

Comment: It's important to understand that SQL (the language) is just a specification. The different products utilizing it (MySQL, PostgreSQL) can take a lot of freedoms on the details. If you use MySQL, you should look at the MySQL documentation specifically. Note that the SQL specification itself is not freely available.

Comment: As I understand it the isolation level is a generally setting do if the cascade is blocked the delete on the table with the foreign key will also be blocked by there transaction level. If you find a syntax to set variable transaction levels by table I would be interested to learn.